# Datatables : jQuery UI tabs : Make tab active with users wise

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, datatables, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using DATA-TABLES : Jquery UI Tab :

TRIED BELOW :

[jsfiddle.net/tNRwZ/18/](http://jsfiddle.net/tNRwZ/18/)

Its working fine.

SHORT :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs( {
        "activate": function(event, ui) {
            var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
            if ( table.length > 0 ) {
                $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }
    } );

    $('table.display').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bJQueryUI": false,

    } );
} );
```

But i want my second tab (sha-2) should be active first.   -- PLS CHECK ABOVE jsfiddle LINK FOR DEMO

Also how i can make active tab with users wise , i means if i have 3 tabs then the resp. tab should be active only to resp. user ( who is login in the system ) .. else other tab should be disable or inactive or not click-able to resp. user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/m7rLY/)**

This is how you can do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs( {
        active: 1,//Tab no.2 "Sha-2" by default active on page load,
        disabled: [ 0, 2 ],//disable tab no. 1 and 3
        "activate": function(event, ui) {
            var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
            if ( table.length > 0 ) {
                $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }
    } );

    $('table.display').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bJQueryUI": false,

    } );
} );
```

**============With PHP code, you will have to do something like:**

```
$("#tabs").tabs( {
<?php
if($_SESSION['current_user']->access == "SUPPORT"){
?>
            active: 1,//Tab no.2 "Sha-2" by default active on page load,
            disabled: [0],//disable tab no. 1
<?php
}
if($_SESSION['current_user']->access == "DESIGNER")
{ 
?>
            active: 0,//Tab no.2 "Sha-1" by default active on page load,
            disabled: [1],//disable tab no. 2
<?php
}
?>

        "activate": function(event, ui) {
            var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
            if ( table.length > 0 ) {
                $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Hey Rahul , thanks ... also i want that tab should be active to resp. login user like :

if($_SESSION['current_user']->access == SUPPORT){      
  active: 1, 
   disabled: [ 0 ], 
}  

if($_SESSION['current_user']->access == DESIGNER){      
  active: 0, 
   disabled: [ 1 ],
}

But its not working

Comment: I have updated my answer, with how you can achieve that with PHP code. Take look at it. Let me know if you have any problem ! Please consider accepting the answer !

Comment: Great its working but .. showing red sign in Netbeans " Expected eof but found }
} ); "

Comment: If it's working then it is great ! Not sure about the error. Maybe not related to this code !

Comment: No its showing near end of Jquery and Tabs thats  }); ... but yes its working ...

Comment: Hey .. i saw there is some issue : if i remove above php code then there is not red sign shown but if php code is place again red sign is shown at the end of query }); .... code is working but the red sign is bit worry me ..

Comment: I think you have forgotten to close the ending brackets `)};` of `$(document).ready(function(){` !

Comment: page is seen proper there is no error in firebug : 

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs( {
<?php
if($_SESSION['current_user']->access == "SUPPORT"){
?>
            active: 1, 
            disabled: [0],
<?php }
if($_SESSION['current_user']->access == "DESIGNER")
{ 
?>
            active: 0, 
            disabled: [1],
<?php } ?>
        "activate": function(event, ui) {
            var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
            if ( table.length > 0 ) {
                $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }
        }
    } );  // here 
}); // here to

Answer (score 2):

to select active tab:

`$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1 })`